# Query returning all system stored procedures listed by MS SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

How can I get all the system stored procedures listed by MS SQL Server (2012) using an SQL query?

Comment: Have you tried anything ? It's something to get on a single search .

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345522.aspx you should go through this .

Comment: @SurajSingh Yes, I answered my own question when I posted it (see below). I did this because I want to keep this information here for future reference. I hope that's OK.

Comment: why not it's a free site :-).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`sysobjects` is deprecated. You can use

```
SELECT QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id)) + '.' + QUOTENAME(name)
FROM   sys.all_objects
WHERE  type = 'P'
       AND is_ms_shipped = 1
```

Comment: Awesome! This even avoids the use of the deprecated sysobjects view. Thank you!

Comment: After reading more about the views available in the `sys` namespace, I noticed that we can query `sys.system_objects` where `type = 'P'` in order to get the system Stored Procedures. `sys.all_objects` contains the user defined ones as well.

Comment: @MihaiTodor - That would be a better way.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT sch.name + '.' + obj.name
  FROM sysobjects obj, sys.schemas sch
  WHERE obj.type = 'P'
    AND sch.schema_id = obj.uid
    AND sch.name = 'sys'
    --AND obj.name like '%my_search_string%'--use this for filtering
  ORDER BY sch.name + '.' + obj.name
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT *
FROM   sys.all_objects
WHERE  type = 'P'
       AND is_ms_shipped = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name, 
       type
  FROM dbo.sysobjects
 WHERE (type = 'P')
```

Comment: This is deprecated as per [http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143729.aspx]

Comment: Nope, this one returns user defined SP, whereas I am interested in the system defined ones.